# Increment MySQL uniq row by only one request

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to increment value unique row, use only one request
Not use select and after condition INSERT OR UPDATE

Table columns **(date, servie)** are used as unique values

**Only one INSERT**

For example

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I found a single solution, but it not work for my

```
INSERT INTO log (`date`,`service`,`count`) VALUES ('2020-12-1','amazon',count+1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date`='2020-12-01',`service`='amazon',`count`=`count`+1;
```

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: *I found a single solution* It must fail with the error `Unknown column 'id_key' in 'field list'`. PS. Your table does not contain unique indices, ODKU will fire never.

Comment: Provide COMPLETE AND UNCHANGED table's CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: The statement of the question was not that I was getting an error, but that I couldn’t make a single request to increase the row, in which, as it turns out, I didn’t know how to insert unique multi keys.

Thank you all, solution is bellow posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define id_key as a unique key in the table (or as the primary key):

```
create table log (
    id_key  int primary key
    dt date not null,
    service varchar(255) not null,
    cnt int not null,
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

Then you can do:

```
insert into t1 (id_key, dt, service, cnt) 
values (1, '2020-12-1', 'amazon', 1)
on duplicate key update 
    dt = values(dt),
    service = values(service),
    cnt = cnt + 1;
```

This attempts to insert a new row in the table, with a `cnt` of of `1`. If `id_key` exists already, then it is updated instead: the date and service are updated, and the count is incremented.

---

If you want to use the date and service as unique keys, then do reflect that in the `create table` statement:

```
create table log (
    id_key  int primary key
    dt date not null,
    service varchar(255) not null,
    cnt int not null,
    unique (dt, service)
) engine = innodb default charset = utf8;
```

And then, it does not really make sense to update these columns on duplicate keys, so:

```
insert into t1 (id_key, dt, service, cnt) 
values (1, '2020-12-1', 'amazon', 1)
on duplicate key update cnt = cnt + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my unique values will be used
date, service

Comment: Thanks, yes man

unique (dt, service) - it is work), set unique for multi rows

Comment: Chuck the PK and upgrade to `PRIMARY KEY(dt, service)`.